# UDF Intentando usar referencias externas para referirse a un libro cerrado

Tags: excel, vba, parametros, enlace, función-personalizada

Estoy intentando crear una UDF que me devuelva la ruta completa hacia un rango que es pasado por parámetro, con el fin de crear un hipervínculo a dicho rango.

Hasta el momento, escribí este código:

```
Function DirCelda(rng As Range) As String

    Application.Volatile
    
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Wb As Workbook

    Set Sh = rng.Parent
    Set Wb = Sh.Parent

    DirCelda = Wb.FullName & "#'" & Sh.Name & "'!" & rng.Address

End Function
```

El cual funciona perfecto con rangos dentro del documento donde está insertada la UDF y con rangos de otros documentos (mientras estos estén abiertos).

Por ejemplo:

```
=DirCelda(F8:G9)
```

Devuelve: **P:\Rodri\LinksExcel.xlsm#'Sheet1'!$F$8:$G$9**

```
=DirCelda('[Caminos.xlsx]Sheet23'!$M$6:$N$22)
```

Devuelve: **P:\Rodri\Caminos.xlsx#'Sheet23'!$M$6:$N$22**

Pero, cuando cierro el documento "Caminos.xlsx", Excel (de acuerdo a lo explicado [acá](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f)) cambia la forma en que define el parámetro que recibe la UDF, agregando la ruta completa del archivo externo.

Entonces, el último ejemplo, se transforma en esto:

```
=DirCelda('P:\Rodri\[Caminos.xlsx]Sheet23'!$M$6:$N$22)
```

Y así me devuelve: **#¡VALOR!**

Estuve intentando de jugar con habilitar y deshabilitar el método Application.Volatile pero cuando la UDF es usada dentro de la fórmula HIPERVINCULO(), Excel recalcula el valor de la UDF, dando error nuevamente.

Intenté convertir esa ruta de archivo cerrada en un String para poder determinar la verdadera ruta al rango, pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error cada vez.

¿Alguno podría ayudarme?

Muchas gracias desde ya. Saludos!

Comment: Si desde una formula se pueden vincular rangos externos y excel cambia dichos vínculos dependiendo de si el origen está o no cerrado. Sabiendo esto: ¿para qué necesitas una función? Si la función en sí misma te la proporciona Excel.

Comment: Porque necesitaría tener la ruta al rango en el formato P:\Rodri\Caminos.xlsx#'Sheet23'!$M$6:$N$22 y no como lo pone Excel en formato 'P:\Rodri\[Caminos.xlsx]Sheet23'!$M$6:$N$22. Cambian los delimitadores que identifican ruta, archivo y hoja. He probado con el método `Application.Caller.Formula` para obtener la ruta en caso que el archivo esté cerrado, pero al ejecutarla dentro de la funcion HIPERVINCULO() me sigue dando error.

Comment: Estás referenciando objetos Worksheet y Workbook, los cuales tienen que estar abiertos para que funcione. Por eso te falla si cierras el libro. PEro ¿Por qué no te vale la función? ¿Para qué la quieres con la almohadilla?